# Problemas entre componentes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Estoy desarrollando una app en angular 5. Tengo dos módulos `module1.ts`, `module2.ts` ambos están incluidos en `app.module.ts`. Ejemplo:

**Module1.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: […],
exports: [componente1Component,…],
declarations: [componente1Component,…..],
providers: [……],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
   entryComponents: […]

})
export class Module1Module {
}
```

**Module2.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [Module1Module,…],
exports: […],
declarations: [componente2Component,…..],
providers: [……],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
   entryComponents: […]

})
export class Module2Module {
}
```

**App.Module.ts**

```
Import {Module1} from …..
Import {Module2} from …..
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  imports: [Module1, Module2],

  providers: [..],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Estos son mis modulos. Cómo el `module1.ts` está importado en el `module2.ts` puedo llamar desde cualquier componente del `module2.ts` los componentes del `module1.ts`. Lo que quiero hacer es ¿cómo llamar los componentes exportados del `module2.ts` en el `module1.ts`?

Comment: ¿Quieres introducir una dependencia cíclica entre tus módulos?

Comment: Si. Reutilizar componentes que esten hechos. ya sea en uno o en el otro.

Comment: Las dependencias cíclicas no solo son mala idea. Son una señal de que algo no está precisamente bien con tu diseño. Por eso la mayoría de los frameworks y lenguajes tienen formas de impedir que ocurran dependencias cíclicas en el código. Mi consejo, crea un tercer módulo y mueve hacia ahí todo el código que necesitas en los otros dos.